# Double fragment instance when it comes from background

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments

I've got the problem with creating multiple fragment instances in OnCreate. When i close the app using Home button and I will return to the app, the fragment instance is created one more time. How can I prevent this?

```
fragment = FragmentMain.newInstance(intent.extras?.getSerializable(DATA_MAIN)).also {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(frameLayout.id, it, FragmentMain::class.java.simpleName)
                .addToBackStack(FragmentMain::class.java.simpleName)
                .commit()
               }
```

Comment: You can check if the fragment already exists and if not, don't create it again. In any case why don't you just add the fragment on the activity layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior, as Android recreates the fragments after process death that are added to the fragment manager.

You're just also adding a 2nd new fragment on top of the one created by Android, which, you probably don't want to do.

```
fragment = when {
    savedInstanceState == null -> FragmentMain.newInstance(intent.extras?.getSerializable(DATA_MAIN)).also {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(frameLayout.id, it, FragmentMain::class.java.simpleName)
                .addToBackStack(FragmentMain::class.java.simpleName)
                .commit()
               }
    else -> supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FragmentMain::class.java.simpleName)
}
```